# How to format numbers in Julia DataFrames notebook?

Tags: dataframe, format, julia, jupyter

Using Julia and `DataFrames.jl`, Floats display in the notebook dataframe output like this:

```
5.97551e5
7.37884e5
3.10031e5
9.6429e5
2.40817e5
```

How would one get the notebook to display them like, for example,

```
5.97e5
7.37e5
3.10e5
9.64e5
2.40e5
```

Or using `Formatting.jl` with the format `format(x,commas=true,autoscale=:finance,precision=2)`:

```
597.55k
737.88k
310.03k
964.29k
240.81k
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use https://github.com/ronisbr/PrettyTables.jl.